# Unable to wire Java ServlextContext in tests for Tomcat project

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlets, autowired

The problem I'm having is that I autowired the servlet context like in the code below by passing it in the constructor. Unfortunately it can't autowire anything when running a test as there is no `ServlextContext` and Spring fails.

```
@Autowired
public MyClass(ServletContext context) {
    this.servletContext = context;
}
```

I don't really need the `ServletContext` autowired for tests, only for when the Tomcat war is run where I then call methods on the `ServletContext`

I'm running a Tomcat Server the project uses Spring.

Comment: You shouldn't require an app server to run a unit test.  You need to think more carefully about how to properly test this app.

Comment: Yeah, I don't need the server to run the tests. However some tests and the server share the same spring configuration files, and one of the files requires a servlet context

Comment: Spring shouldn't be part of your tests.  That's what mocks are for.  Create them in your JUnit test and manually inject them.  It'll keep your unit tests focused on the class you want to test; they'll run faster, too.

Comment: That is true, though we're in the process of replacing our tests to mocks so some tests are mock tests and some aren't

Comment: Why in god's name do you unit tests depend on what server you deploy your project on? This is either an X-Y problem or there is something **seriously** wrong with your project

Comment: They don't depend on the server the project is deployed in. 
Some tests classes have `@Autowired` beans because they didn't bother mocking up the methods. So they are run with a spring context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm using Spring, I fixed this by implementing `ServletContextAware` and adding this method. The method is never called if there is no context, so servletContext will remain `null` if none is available.

`public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        this.servletContext = servletContext;
}`

Then I just check `if(servletContext==null)` before running the parts of the code that actually need the servlet context.

Comment: I'm checking if it's null before running code that requires servletContext as it'll get `NullPointerException`s

Comment: still no need of checking

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Autowired
    ServletContext context;
```

i thinks the best practise is to go with above approach because usually,
its the model class we pass through methods.and you can't get the ServletContext from a method parameter this will not work.

```
public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        this.servletContext = servletContext;
}
```

and you can implement `ServletContextAware` interface to your `controller` class and then you can override  `setServletContext` method to achieve this.

```
private ServletContext context;

@Override
public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
    this.servletContext = servletContext;
}
```